# Toastify the same toast is displayed on all pages

Tags: reactjs

I have an error page which must display a toast if there is an error but the toast is displayed several times in the page and in the other pages how to limit it to a single display.I use redux I want to limit the display of toasts in one go in the pages no more than once.my code

```
 import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
 import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
 import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
 const Index= (props) => {
 const afficheerror= useSelector((state) => state.afficheerror);
 const erreur= useSelector((state) => state.erreur);
   
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
   
 function afficheToast({mymessage}){
   
   const Properties= {
       position: "top-center",
       autoClose: 5000,
       hideProgressBar: false,
       closeOnClick: true,
       pauseOnHover: true,
       draggable: true,
       progress: undefined,
       limit:1
       }
   return(
       <div className=''>
           {toast.error(`${mymessage} `,Properties)}
       </div>
   )
 }
 const MessageError = (error) => {
   
   switch (error) {
     case 410:
       return (
           <div><afficheToast message= 'My erreur'/></div>
       );
     case 404:
       return (
          <div><afficheToast message= 'My erreur'/></div>
       );
     case 422:
       return (
       <div><afficheToast message= 'My erreur'/></div>
     )
     
     
     default:
       return <div></div>;
   }
 };
 return (
   <>
     {afficheerror && erreur && <div >{MessageError(error)}</div>}
     <ToastContainer  limit={1}  />
   </>
 );


 };
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: doesn't seem the `MessageError` is inside the `ToastContainter`

Comment: he must be inside or outside can you give me an example ?